# Can you use named parameters in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo, laravel

I use Oracle as a database layer, but the problem is that oracle via OCI8 (i made a PDO userspace driver) only supports named parameters in SQL statements and doesn't support positioned parameters. (Such as using multiple ?)

At a base, it's Laravel's Eloquent, that generates the SQL, but i can't find any documentation on how to override the construction of parameters.

I'd like to be able to create named parameters in the form of ":name" instead of placing numerous "?" throughout the query.

Can this be done? My guess is it has something to do with the Database Grammar classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, if someone has a better solution, go ahead a submit it or maybe tell me what could be wrong with my temporary solution. I replace all "?" with ":autoparam" with a parameter increment creating ":autoparam0", ":autoparam1", ":autoparam2", etc.

```
    //Replace ? with a pseudo named parameter
    $newStatement = null;
    $parameter = 0;
    while($newStatement !== $statement)
    {
        if($newStatement !== null)
        {
            $statement = $newStatement;
        }
        $newStatement = preg_replace('/\?/', ':autoparam'.$parameter, $statement, 1);
        $parameter++;
    }
    $statement = $newStatement;
```

Then, when i receive a request to bind a parameter from PDO, i check if the parameter is numeric. In most languages, as far as i know, numeric indexes are invalid identifiers, so i can safely assume, at least for my PDO Userspace driver that i can replace the numeric parameter name with:

```
    //Replace the first @oci8param to a pseudo named parameter
    if(is_numeric($parameter))
    {
        $parameter = ':autoparam'.$parameter;
    }
```

It works for now, i need to do more tests with laravel to see if problem appears in a different score, but so far, it seems allright...

Comment: What files did you edit there? I was just scanning through the code to see how it handled the binding.

Comment: I just edited my own PDO Userspace driver, it now has nothing to do with Laravel...

Comment: Have you come across this? Hopefully it's just what you're looking for. https://github.com/jfelder/Laravel-OracleDB

Comment: Yes, i'm using it as a base for my Laravel-OCI8 package but the problem, like i said, is part of OCI8 not Laravel nor PDO_OCI. PDO_OCI doesn't provide all functionalities,probably due to a lack of community support. Since i don't know C/C++ well enough and didn't have time to code this at work, i created my own PDO_OCI8 layer that uses the PHP Userspace to create a real PDO Driver. Works fine now, thanks though