# Laravel 5.2 oracle database PDOException

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

I am working on xamp, using laravel 5.2 and trying to connect oracle database
here I want to get values in tinker:

```
DB::table('dept')->get();
```

with this error:

```
PDOException with message 'could not find driver'
```

my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=Mydb
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

my database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

...

```
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Mydb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'db_username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Comment: You need to install the driver: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php#ref.pdo-sqlsrv.installation

Comment: will this driver work for oracle as well?

Comment: Wait, why are you using sqlsrv to connect to an Oracle DB? That driver is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: ok i see. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database
i thought laravel will make this work for oracle as well.

Comment: i there in laravel a connection to oracle similar to sql server?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880719/connecting-to-oracle-codeigniter-vs-laravel

Comment: thanks, will i give it a try

Comment: I have installed yajra/laravel-oci8 library but iam getting same error
PDOException with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: Update your question with the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Oracle client in your machine: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Install/enable Oracle for PHP. That will depend on your operation system. In windows, I believe you only need to enable on your php.ini, `extension=pdo_oci.dll`. In linux, you need to install, with `apt get` or similar in your distro, or recompile PHP with instructions on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Use this library in your Laravel project: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8

In `config/database.php`:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'my_connection'),

'connections' => [
    'my_connection' => [
        'driver'   => 'oracle',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'service_name' => env('DB_SERVICE_NAME', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ],
    ],
```

In your `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=my_connection
DB_HOST=111.111.111.111
DB_SERVICE_NAME=service
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Comment: thanks, my problem was with oracle oci driver, i have it installed succesfully